# How "at most one" cyclic group means "exactly one " cyclic groups $?$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$G$  is  a  finite  group  of  order  $n$  and  the  equivalence  relation  on $G$  is $$x\equiv y\quad \text{iff}\quad  (x)=(y)$$

Given  that  for  any  divisor  $d$  of  $n$ ,  $G$  has  at most  one  cyclic  subgroup  of  order  $d$ . Let  the  equivalence  class  of  $x$  be  denoted  by  $C(x)$. Since  equivalence  relation  $$|G|=\sum |C(x)|$$  where  the  sum  runs  over  all  the  elements  of  $G$.

Since  $$|C(x)| \le \phi(d)  \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ n=\sum_{d|n} \phi(d)$$   we  can  write  $$n=\sum |C(x)| \le \sum_{d|n} \phi(d) =n $$ i.e.  $$\sum |C(x)|= \sum_{d|n} \phi(d)$$

Now  what  I  do  not  get  is  how   this  last  equation   can  imply  that  number  of  cyclic  subgroups ,  that  was  said  to  be  "at  most  one"  is  actually  "exactly  one" . 
  Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: We have shown there exists an element of order $n$ in $G$, so that $G$ is cyclic. Hence it has exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for all divisors $d\mid n$. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93515/if-an-abelian-group-g-has-order-n-and-at-most-one-subgroup-of-order-d-for).

Comment: @DietrichBurde  :  Where  did  we  show  that  in  this  proof ?

Comment: $G$ has at least $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$ whenever $d$ divides $n$. 
So it has elements of order $n$. Hence $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde :  How  can  you  say  that ?  I  read  exactly   this  proof  in  a  book  and  cannot  understand  how  the  conclusion  came?

Comment: See the answer of Pierre-Yves Gaillard at the link above. Isn't it exactly the conclusion you want ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde :  What  link $?$

Comment: @user80631 The link in the first comment

Comment: @DietrichBurde :  The  link  in   your  first  comment ,  is  it  $?$

Comment: Oh  thanks  @Rememberme .

Answer (score 1):

As seen, $|C(x)|\le\phi(d) $ whenever $x$ is of order $d$. If there were any $x$ and $d$ with $|C(x)|<\phi(d)$ (where of course $d\mid n$), then you'd have $\sum |C(x)|<\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d)=n$

Answer (score 0):

A cyclic group is a group which contains elements of its own order.

By the assumption $G$ has at most $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$ whenever $d$ divides $n$ (here n is the order of the group G)

But we know that $G$ has atleast $\phi(d)$ elements of order d whenever $d$ divides n.

By the above two statements we can say that $G$ has elements of order $n$. Hence $G$ is cyclic(as I stated earlier).